# Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined... Why?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

So this is my code that´s is supposed to loop through the pivot's SUPPLIER FILTER based on a list located in the same worksheet. After every loop it has to upload the file to the intranet in a .pdf format.

```
Sub Upload()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim lLoop As Long

    Set pt = Sheets("To Supplier").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[Query].[SUPPLIER].[SUPPLIER]")

    Sheets("To Supplier").Select

    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        On Error Resume Next
        pf.CurrentPage = pi.Value
        On Error GoTo 0
        If pf.CurrentPage = pi.Value Then
            If lLoop = 0 Then
                With Sheets("To Supplier").PageSetup
                    .CenterFooter = pi.Value
                    .LeftHeader = pt.Name
                    .LeftFooter = Now
                End With
            End If
            Range("L2").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                                    "=INDEX(RC[-6]:R[59]C[-5],MATCH(R[1]C[-10],RC[-6]:R[59]C[-6],0),2)"
                                    Sheets("To Supplier").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                                    "http://collaborationx.com/portalone/sourcing/Supplier%20documents/" & Cell("L2").Value _
                                    & "/Evaluations/" & Cell("L2").Value & "%20Credits.pdf" _
                                    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                                    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
            lLoop = lLoop + 1
        End If
    Next pi
End Sub
```

However, It keeps throwing me off... now the prob is that it says the function is not defined, before the problem was with the references...

Comment: Which line is the error thrown?

Comment: In the FormulaR1C1, you have a couple of `Cell` that should rather be `Cells`. When you get "Sub or Function not defined", it's enough to click on "OK" to see _what_ is not defined, the debugger is the best friend of the developer ;)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Thank you, I noticed... but now that i run it it does nothing... at all

Comment: @FatimaDelCarpio well, this might be due to thousands of reasons: code structure, wrong procedures, problems with data etc. The best thing to do, always in programming, is to [debug](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). We cannot do much if we don't have a precise error and more information, this is a job that only the developer with the whole code and the data in front of her can do.

Answer (score 0):

`Cell("L2")` is not defined. You probably wanted `Range("L2")` but since you selected that range before you could use `ActiveCell`. Example, HTH.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(RC[-6]:R[59]C[-5],MATCH(R[1]C[-10],RC[-6]:R[59]C[-6],0),2)"

    Dim exportFileName As String
    exportFileName = "http://collaborationx.com/portalone/sourcing/Supplier%20documents/{0}/Evaluations/{0}%20Credits.pdf"
    exportFileName = Replace(exportFileName, "{0}", ActiveCell.Value)

    Sheets("To Supplier").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=exportFileName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```